# MySQL monthly report inaccuracies

Tags: mysql, datediff

My company has introduced an on-call rota for the IT department. I created a MySQL table which details who takes on-call, when they take it and when it's taken by the next individual on completion of each shift.

Below is a sample (with names removed) taken from late May - early June:

```
|seq__num   |   date_taken  |   date_relinquished   |   user    |
|-----------|---------------|-----------------------|-----------|
|   1       |   2015-05-29  |       2015-06-05      |   A       |
|   2       |   2015-06-05  |       2015-06-06      |   B       |
|   3       |   2015-06-06  |       2015-06-07      |   C       |
|   4       |   2015-06-07  |       2015-06-10      |   B       |
|   5       |   2015-06-10  |       2015-06-10      |   A       |
|   6       |   2015-06-10  |       2015-06-12      |   B       |
|   7       |   2015-06-12  |       2015-06-19      |   C       |
|   8       |   2015-06-19  |       2015-07-03      |   D       |
```

The next step is to produce an automated monthly report which queries the table and outputs how many days each user held on-call for so Finance know how much they need paying. Currently this is counted manually.

The query I've got is:

```
SELECT user, SUM(DATEDIFF(date_relinquished, date_taken))
AS duration
FROM on-call_log
WHERE YEAR(date_relinquished) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date_relinquished) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY user
```

While this does work if on-call is held perfectly within a month. If someone is on-call from the one month into the next, it reports the full period, which produces inaccuracies. Instead of reporting as if June actually has 30 days, like so:

```
A   4
B   6
C   8
D   12
```

It takes into account how person A took on-call from the previous month and person D took it into the following month, like so:

```
A   7
B   6
C   8
D   14
```

I'm a bit of a loss as to how to make it report accurately. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, for clarity can you specify the desired result.

Comment: I'd like it to report the number of days each person held on-call for from the previous month. Currently, for example it doesn't take into account that June had 30 days.

Comment: Yes. Please provide the desired result, across the desired time span

Comment: If a fellow takes on-call on July 31 and lets it go on August 1, does he get credit for one day in July and one day in August?  What if he takes it on August 1 and lets it go on August 3? Is that three days in August.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a calendar table - even a calendar table holding all plausible dates into the future is depressingly small!

Then your query might look like this - I've assumed that on-calls are only counted once per day per user (DISTINCT)...

```
SELECT user
     , DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m') month
     , COUNT(DISTINCT dt) total 
  FROM calendar x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON x.dt BETWEEN y.date_taken AND y.date_relinquished 
 GROUP 
    BY month
     , user;
+------+---------+-------+
| user | month   | total |
+------+---------+-------+
| A    | 2015-05 |     3 |
| A    | 2015-06 |     6 |
| B    | 2015-06 |     8 |
| C    | 2015-06 |    10 |
| D    | 2015-06 |    12 |
| D    | 2015-07 |     3 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Ah, never thought of a calendar table Strawberry, I've created one which I'll start messing around with using your query above. Cheers.

Comment: Have you been in a coma?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Other projects & complications arose, ensued, were overcome.